Expo (SDK 51) not finding app/_layout.tsx in expo-router/entry.js
I've been working on my Expo project using the default template for a week now, using the _layout.tsx component in the app directory as my entry point:
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { LogBox } from "react-native";

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true);

const RootLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
}

export default RootLayout;

Yesterday, when starting my Metro Server, Expo generated an index.tsx component in my app directory and started showing this screen on start up:

None of the changes I make to that newly generated index.tsx file is changing the above screen, and I cannot seem to find the above screen's component code. It seems that the expo-router/entry.js file is not detecting my _layout.tsx or the new index.tsx file.
Here is my package.json information:
{
  "name": "testproject",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.1",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "expo": "~51.0.28",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-device": "^6.0.2",
    "expo-document-picker": "~12.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.9",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "firebase": "^11.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

Things that I've tried to do:

I have tried clearing the cache by running expo start -c

I have tried specifying the entryPoint in my app.json file:


{
  "expo": {
    "entryPoint": "./app/_layout.tsx"
  }
}


I have attempted to rename the _layout.tsx file to _app.tsx or index.js

The only other question I found on this topic was this one, but it didn't solve the problem:
Expo Router v3 does not recognize "_layout.tsx" in custom entry file



I have the same exact problem, and still can't solve it.
